# Running same hook for deployment and configuration deployment

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon Linux 2, I'm trying to have the same hook executed for a deployment (code deployment) and a configuration deployment, without having to duplicate my code in two different spots.

According to [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) eb will run hooks in `.platform/hooks/prebuild` within a deployment intial steps, but will run hooks in `.platform/confighooks/prebuild` in case of a configuration deployment.

My files look like this.

```
.platform
├── hooks
│   └── prebuild
│       ├── 00_hookname.sh
│       ├── 01_hookname.sh
│       └── 99_basic_auth.sh
└── httpd
    └── conf.d
        └── elasticbeanstalk
            ├── directory.conf
            ├── hardening.conf
            └── headers.conf
```

I'm trying to find a way to have 99_basic_auth.sh to run for a deployment **and** for a configuration deployment without having to duplicate that code.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do such a thing is to simply call the first script from the second one.

```
.platform
├── hooks
│   └── prebuild
│       ├── 00_hookname.sh
│       ├── 01_hookname.sh
│       └── 99_basic_auth.sh
├── confighooks
│   └── prebuild
│       └── 99_basic_auth.sh
└── httpd
    └── conf.d
        └── elasticbeanstalk
            ├── directory.conf
            ├── hardening.conf
            └── headers.conf
```

Where the content of `.platform/confighooks/prebuild/99_basic_auth.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

/bin/bash "/var/app/current/.platform/hooks/prebuild/99_basic_auth.sh"
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be also be done with symlinks, which I prefer over having a script calling another script:

```
mkdir -p .platform/confighooks/prebuild
ln -sr .platform/hooks/prebuild/99_basic_auth.sh .platform/confighooks/prebuild
```